# How to resize div to 50%

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries, responsive

The problem is I can't get the boxes to resize to 50%, they just stay the full width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Mobile Styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F09A9D;
    /* Red */
  }
}


/* Tablet Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .sign-up,
  .feature-1,
  .feature-2,
  .feature-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Desktop Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  body {
    background-color: #B2D6FF;
    /* Blue */
  }
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #5995DA;
  height: 80px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #B2D6FF;
}

.content {
  background-color: #EAEDF0;
  height: 600px;
}

.sign-up {
  background-color: #D6E9FE;
}

.feature-1 {
  background-color: #F5CF8E;
}

.feature-2 {
  background-color: #F09A9D;
}

.feature-3 {
  background-color: #C8C6FA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Responsive Design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="section menu"></div>
    <div class="section header">
      <img src="images/header.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section content">
      <img src="images/content.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section sign-up">
      <img src="images/sign-up.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-1">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-2">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-3">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can u give a screenshot for what u want to achieve ?

Comment: Not sure without working example, but try to add "flex: 1 1 50%;" and min/max-width of 50% to the Tablet-Styles.

Answer (score 0):

Div's with the class `feature` have another class called `section`, I see that you have mentioned the width for section as 100% that is the reason why it is taking entire width, even after mentioning the width of the feature class as 50%.

You can either remove the width property of sections in media screens and set the features class with a width of 50% or set the section class a width of 50% in media screens

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Mobile Styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F09A9D;
    width: 100%!important;
    /* Red */
  }
}


/* Tablet Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .sign-up,
  .feature-1,
  .feature-2,
  .feature-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Desktop Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  body {
    background-color: #B2D6FF;
    /* Blue */
  }
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section {
  /* width: 100%; this is overriding your feature class properties*/
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #5995DA;
  height: 80px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #B2D6FF;
}

.content {
  background-color: #EAEDF0;
  height: 600px;
}

.sign-up {
  background-color: #D6E9FE;
}

.feature-1 {
  background-color: #F5CF8E;
}

.feature-2 {
  background-color: #F09A9D;
}

.feature-3 {
  background-color: #C8C6FA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Responsive Design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="section menu"></div>
    <div class="section header">
      <img src="images/header.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section content">
      <img src="images/content.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section sign-up">
      <img src="images/sign-up.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-1">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-2">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-3">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your media queries so that they appear **after** `.section`. Otherwise, you are overriding them.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #5995DA;
  height: 80px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #B2D6FF;
}

.content {
  background-color: #EAEDF0;
  height: 600px;
}

.sign-up {
  background-color: #D6E9FE;
}

.feature-1 {
  background-color: #F5CF8E;
}

.feature-2 {
  background-color: #F09A9D;
}

.feature-3 {
  background-color: #C8C6FA;
}


/* Mobile Styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F09A9D;
    /* Red */
  }
}


/* Tablet Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .sign-up,
  .feature-1,
  .feature-2,
  .feature-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Desktop Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  body {
    background-color: #B2D6FF;
    /* Blue */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Responsive Design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="section menu"></div>
    <div class="section header">
      <img src="images/header.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section content">
      <img src="images/content.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section sign-up">
      <img src="images/sign-up.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-1">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-2">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="section feature-3">
      <img src="images/feature.svg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```